# why am i getting � instead of double qoutes?

Tags: php, html, database, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to call some data from my local database to my extension using PHP. But while calling I don't know why the **double quotes** is shown as �. so can some help me out with this.

I also tried using

```
htmlspecialchars()
```

but it did not help at all.

thank you

Comment: it looks like. But I am really not sure because it is replacing only the double quotes and single quotes.

Comment: What I'm not sure if it is actually storing the values correctly in your database, rather than printing them correctly. What encoding are you using in your database?

Comment: You could try to store your quotes by replacing them with &quot; before you insert them into the database to make sure they always will load.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
$var = "YOUR TEXT";
$foo = mb_substr($var,0,142, "utf-8");
```

> **DESCRIPTION** : If you see that character (� U+FFFD "REPLACEMENT CHARACTER") it usually means that the text itself is encoded in some form of single byte encoding but interpreted in one of the unicode encodings (UTF8 or UTF16).
>
> If it were the other way around it would (usually) look something like this: Ã¤.
>
> Probably the original encoding is ISO-8859-1, also known as Latin-1. You can check this without having to change your script: Browsers give you the option to re-interpret a page in a different encoding -- in Firefox use "View" -> "Character Encoding".

IF ABOVE THING IS NOT WORKING TRY THIS:

> To make the browser use the correct encoding, add an HTTP header like this:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1");
or put the encoding in a meta tag:

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

Alternatively you could try to read from the database in another encoding (UTF-8, preferably) or convert the text with iconv().
```

Comment: @Patricia Moore check is it useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

**just try this header if it works means comment it**

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-7');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

`&#34;` or `&quot;`

If you use an `HTML entity` name or a `hexadecimal` number, the character will always display correctly.
This is independent of what character set (encoding) your page uses!